# Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I have done hours of debugging and I am unable to find the solution.

```js
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { configureStore } from '@redux.js/toolkit';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

let reducer = combineReducers({
  // contains all reducers
});

// here all our data will lie
const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = configureStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Error:

[image]

I just want a todo list to be displayed on browser, which I have written in my `App.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
const store=configureStore(
    {
        reducer,
        initialState,
        composeWithDevTools( ... )
    }
)

export default store;
```

**Help for posting code in Stack Overflow:**

1. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
2. [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

The [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) utility takes a single argument object with properties `reducer`, `middleware`, `devTools`, `preloadedState`, and `enhancers`.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // contains all reducer functions
});

const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore({ // <-- single object argument
  reducer: rootReducer,
  preloadedState: initialState,
});

export default store;
```

Note that I didn't include the `Thunk` middleware since Redux Toolkit comes with the Thunk middleware by default, and I didn't include any regarding `devTool` since these are also enabled by default.

Comment: @AdityaPandey Certainly welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!